# match Prop to Type without excluded middle

Tags: logic, coq

Coq accepts to `match` a proof of `Prop`, only when the return type is `Prop` (ie only to produce another proof). From what I understand, this avoids the following paradox :

```
Require Import Hurkens.

Inductive BoolProp : Prop :=
| falseP : BoolProp | trueP : BoolProp.

Axiom b2p : BoolProp -> Prop.
Axiom b2p_spec : b2p falseP = False /\ b2p trueP = True.
Axiom EM : forall P:Prop, P \/ ~P.

Definition p2b (P : Prop) : BoolProp :=
  match EM P with
  | or_introl _ => trueP
  | or_intror _ => falseP
  end.

Lemma crash : False.
Proof.
  destruct b2p_spec. 
  apply (NoRetractFromSmallPropositionToProp.paradox BoolProp p2b b2p).
  intros. unfold p2b in H1. destruct (EM A).
  exact a. exfalso. rewrite H in H1. exact H1.
  intros. unfold p2b. destruct (EM A). rewrite H0. trivial. contradiction.
Qed.
```

The `match` restriction prevents the direct definition of `b2p`, which I had to axiomatize to produce this proof of `False`.

But note that I also assumed the excluded middle `EM`. Coq wants to be compatible with it, so that people can do classical logic. However, if I want to stay constructive and use Coq without any axioms, then is there a risk of contradiction in allowing `match` from `Prop` to `Type` ? In the above, `falseP` and `trueP` would be provably different by this kind of `match`, so proof irrelevance would be refuted. Then the classical set-theoretical model of Coq would no longer work and we would need another model.

Note that I'm not asking why Coq introduced `Prop` or what design choices Coq made, or what is the intended usage of `Prop` (I think I know those parts), it is rather a theoretical question about `Prop`.

Comment: The Hurkens module contains various "paradoxes", in particular does "Large universes are not retracts of Prop" answer your question? https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.Hurkens.html

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I don't think it does. This paradox tells there is no surjection `Prop -> Type`. My question is rather about functions `P -> T`, with `P : Prop` and `T : Type`. I do not request them to be surjective either.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, only an idea off the top of my head, but it is too long for a comment.

`Prop` is impredicative, i.e., given any type `A` and `B : A -> Prop`, the type `forall x, B x` is in `Prop`.

If you allow `match`ing on `Prop` when eliminating into `Type`, then it should be the case that every type is isomorphic to a proposition, like this:

```
Inductive AsProp (A : Type) : Prop :=
  | i : forall x : A, AsProp A.
```

Now I think we should be able to show that `i : A -> I A` has an inverse by using the forbidden `match`.

But now we are awfully close to showing that `Type` is impredicative as well, are we not? This is going to be a problem, because by a result of Coquand it is inconsisten to have an impredicative universe which contains another impredicative universe.

I just don't see how to get impredicativity for all types, honestly, otherwise this could be an answer.

Comment: I suspect you can weaken the assumptions of NoRetractFromTypeToProp in https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.Hurkens.html to only require an equivalence rather than an equality.  (Your answer gives that every universe is impredicative up to equivalence, i.e., every universe U contains a type equivalent to `forall X : U, P X`.)  Note also that your inductive is in the standard library under the name `inhabited `.